# Error with my mysqldump file

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to import stored procedures and functions contained in mysqldump file from my local machine to a production machine using phpmyadmin. However, phpmyadmin throws this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'SET @saved_sql_mode       = @@sql_mode */'

I used this code to create the dump file

```
mysqldump mas --routines --skip-triggers --skip-comments --skip-set-charset --no-create-info --no-data > mas.sql -u root -p
```

I know the output is quite long but please bear with me and help me solve this and what could be causing it.

Here is the dump file [output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4DKJUiTV3kTbmNKMEVKN1I2ZW8/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Do you have to use `phpMyAdmin` to import it? Can you use the CLI on the server and use `mysql < mas.sql`?

Comment: @Barmar will that change the outcome

Comment: That's essentially what import does.

Comment: Which MySQL versions are you exporting from and importing in to?